# sharing code between team projects

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

Ive been following the [Branching in TFS 2010: Part V (Sharing Common Libraries)](http://www.thecodeconnection.com/2011/11/branching-in-tfs-2010-part-v-sharing.html) guide on sharing code between team projects but im having problems sharing a dll from my common code project to another project.  It states that the project im trying to branch too already exists.  How can i branch a dll into a lib folder of another project

Comment: Are you selecting the dll in source control explorer, or are you selecting the folder?

Comment: @John Saunders selecting the dll